# Creating a Condition in Python that pops everything that doesn't have a certain starting

Tags: python, list, slice

So, I'm trying to create a loop in python that will pop an element out of a list if it doesn't start with >\n, like below

```
">\n Item"
```

This is the code I have so far

```
for i in clean:
    if ((clean[i])[0:2]) != (">\n"):
        clean.pop[i]
```

All the elements are strings and I'm getting a TypeError: string indices must be integers

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `clean` is a `list`, the `for i in clean` will iterate over *elements* of `clean` in `i`, not indices. Also, `pop` is a function, not a list or a dict, you can't use square brackets on it. Also, removing elements from a list while iterating over the list is ill-advised, because you'll skip over some elements as they shift towards the front simultaneously while your iterator proceeds in the other direction. So your corrected code might be:

```
for i in range(len(clean) - 1, -1, -1):
    if clean[i][0:2] != ">\n":
        clean.pop(i)
```

It is easier if you just use a comprehension to create a new list:

```
clean = [line for line in clean if line.startswith(">\n")]
```